# Stop Spring Application If Database Connection is not available

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my spring boot application, we are connecting to our oracle database.
After trying to connect to DB 2-3 times, I want my application to shut down automatically if the DB connection is failed.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways but one quick way is to use `exit` method of SpringApplication.

```
public YourClass{

@Autowired
ApplicationContext ctx;

public dbconnectivityCheck{
  //if connection attempts failed
  SpringApplication.exit(ctx);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Ashish,
What we have done right now is through the scheduler we are fetching some data from DB, and if are getting any connection related exception, we are simply calling system.exit(0);
Now, we are looking if we can check on application startup that db connection is not available then we don't want our spring application to continue to start and should be stopped.
Can you please suggest any approach for this?

Comment: @HimanshuGupta, your new requirement  quite different requirement than your original question . Can you please accept this answer if this address original question?

By the way, for your new requirement, you don't need to do anything if your database connection is created via spring datasource, because if connection is not available by any reason (say host is unreachable or connections exhausted ) then spring boot won't start its execution.

Comment: Not sure why it is not happening in my case, my spring application is getting started(ofcourse I am getting db connection exception), however my when i am trying to run my project it is not working.

Comment: @HimanshuGupta, sorry didn't get your issue.. you said you got db connection exception, if you are getting such exception, spring boot will stop & same can be seen in logs.  I am unable to get what you mean by `however my when i am trying to run my project it is not working`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   SpringApplication.run(Your_Application.class, args).close();
> ```

Use this to close the context and release all resources as well.

Comment: But how i will know if the db connection is lost.?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Here is the answer for my question, basically `ApplicationContext` and `CommandLineRunner` did the magic here. Please check the image.